# Extract last column values and sum it in 2nd last column

Tags: vba, ms-word

[image]

```
Sub Table1()
Dim FirstTable As Table
Dim value1, value2 As Integer
Set FirstTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
iLastRow = FirstTable.Rows.Count
value1 = Left(FirstTable.Rows(1).Cells(2).Range.Text, Len(FirstTable.Rows(1).Cells(2).Range.Text) - 2)
value2 = Left(FirstTable.Rows(2).Cells(2).Range.Text, Len(FirstTable.Rows(2).Cells(2).Range.Text) - 2)
Total = value1 + value2
End Sub
```

this was something I was trying to write and an error was occurring due to the  vertically merged cells

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the merges? They cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: Since this is apparently a table in a template, why are you not using formula fields to calculate the values? That way, all you'd need after the data are input is ActiveDocument.Fields.Update.